# Xcode 6.1 and Xctool failed when running tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctool

i have got working tests, but when i try to test them they failed on prepaire emulator. I have tried to build with xctool. I'am running in Jenkins my nodes connected via jnlp, also i have tried to build it directly on server, and nothing. How to fix it?
Xcode 6.1
My commands for build, which i try:

1) command for iphone 5:

```
xctool -scheme QA -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 5'  test
```

here output:

```
run-test QVCTests.xctest (iphonesimulator8.2, iPhone 5, application-test)
[Info] Installing 'com.qvc.iphoneapp' ...2015-04-16 14:43:56.315 xctool[12732:2a07] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
[Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.qq.iphoneapp' but failed. (287 ms)
[Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 2 more times (0 ms)
[Info] Shut down iOS Simulator... (0 ms)
[Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (15 ms)
[Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings at path "..../Devices/260A25AD-4160-42A2-AC06-7F6A069093AE/data" (4089 ms)
[Info] Installing 'com.qvc.iphoneapp' ...2015-04-16 14:44:01.540 xctool[12732:2a07] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
[Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.qq.iphoneapp' but failed. (11 ms)
[Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 1 more time (0 ms)
[Info] Shut down iOS Simulator... (0 ms)
[Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (14 ms)
[Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings at path "../Devices/260A25AD-4160-42A2-AC06-7F6A069093AE/data" (3621 ms)
[Info] Installing 'com.qq.iphoneapp' ...2015-04-16 14:44:06.191 xctool[12732:2a07] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
[Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.qq.iphoneapp' but failed. (12 ms)
```

2) command:

```
xcodebuild -scheme QA -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 5' test
```

here output:

```
xcodebuild[12769:4407]  iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
```

3) command:

```
 xctool -scheme QA -sdk iphonesimulator8.2 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' -workspace project.xcworkspace -configuration Acceptance test
```

here output:

```
Failed to query the list of test cases in the test bundle: 2015-04-16 ...Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/sim: No simulator devices appear to be running.  Setting data directories to /var/empty.
 sim[7634:303] DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES contains possible bad values.  Caller beware: /usr/local/Cellar/xctool/HEAD/libexec/lib/otest-query-lib-ios.dylib
```

Error spawning child process: Bad CPU type in executable

4) command

```
xcodebuild -scheme QA -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 6' test
```

here output:

```
 iPhoneSimulator: Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me simply rebooting the Mac resolved the

```
Could not launch simulator: -600
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

> Error spawning child process: Bad CPU type in executable

That indicates that the executable was built for an incorrect architecture.  Given that you're running in an iPhone 5 Simulator, your executable will need to be built for i386.

If that is not the problem, please provide more of the build log to show how your executable is being built, linked, and installed.